How do I upload a large number of small files in Firebase when a new user is created?
I'm currently writing a Firebase function that creates a bunch of new blobs in cloud storage for each new user when they first sign up.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { initializeApp, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getStorage } = require('firebase-admin/storage');
const fs = require('fs');

const serviceAccount = require('./###-firebase_service_account_key.json');

initializeApp({
   credential: cert(serviceAccount),
   storageBucket: '###.appspot.com'
 });

const bucket = getStorage().bucket();

exports.onUserCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

   const { email, uid } = user;
 
   //console.log('new user created! ' + uid);
   
   const directoryPath = 'new_user_template';
   const fileList = fs.readdirSync(directoryPath);
   
   const uploadPromises = [];
   
   console.log('STARTING UPLOAD');
   for (let i = 0; i<fileList.length; i++) {

      const fileName = fileList[i];

      if (fileName === '.DS_Store') {
         continue;
      }

      const filePath = directoryPath + '/' + fileName;

      const options = {
         destination: 'users/' + uid + '/' + fileName
      };

      const uploadPromise = bucket.upload(filePath, options);
      uploadPromises.push(uploadPromise);
   }
   
   return Promise.all(uploadPromises)
   .then(() => console.log('ALL FILES UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY'))
   .catch(error => console.error('Error uploading files', error));
   
});

The function currently works by simply looping through files in that function's local storage directory new_user_template/ and uploading each file to cloud storage one at a time.
This works fine when I need to upload a small amount of files, but stops working when I try to upload a large amount of small files.
In my case, I have around 30,000 .pkl objects that each weigh about 5kb each that I'd like to upload to cloud storage when the user first signs up.
When I try my current method in the firebase emulator, it crashes and when I deploy it to test on GCP, I get a timeout.
I fundamentally need a way for these 30,000 objects to be accessible to the new user on cloud storage very shortly after their account has been created and this current upload method seems to be the wrong route.
=> Question: How should one go about uploading all of these files on new user creation? I'm open to all suggestions.

Show the code in question so someone can even start to guess.  Maybe my math  is off, but 30,000 x 5kb = 1,500,000, which is a decent size of data, but the time it takes to do that many objects is likely longer than your timeout for upload, perhaps you can adjust the timeout to make it longer and see if it works, hangs, or still errors.

But if small amount of files work (upload is working) but large amount does not, its very likely a timeout  issue, so see if you can adjust it to be much longer, that or try to do multiple small batches in sequence until the entire pool of files is done.

@easleyfixed code has been added! And yes, when I've tried this code deployed on GCP, I do get the timeout error. The problem is that I need to upload these as fast as possible as the user may need to access any of these 30,000 objects shortly after user creation.

Not sure how to impliment it with googles requirements, but in a traditional server system you have 2 options :  1) increase the timeout (not sure where that settings is) 2) break the 30,000 objects into 5k blocks and do 6 sets of blocks if that makes sense.

Why do you need to create a copy of all of these files for each individual user? Can't you instead grant the new user access to the files in their original (shared) location?

They might be generated based on criteria, and rights need to be updated, a direct copy would give them ownership of those files, thats my guess.

What if you add something to your code to increase the timeout like this :
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client(timeout=300)
Thats 300 seconds .. which should be long enough I would hope ..  But change any variables to match your current code, but the concept is there.

Copy from a predefined read only cloud storage bucket.
Set a longer timeout (up to 540 seconds) during cloud function development.
Use Cloud Run with a longer timeout.

"When I try my current method in the firebase emulator, it crashes" - what is the error?  "and when I deploy it to test on GCP, I get a timeout" - have you tried increasing the timeout configured for the function?  Please edit the question to show your debugging details.

@FrankvanPuffelen Good question. The reason is that, even though the objects all start off the same for each user, they will ultimately be modified over time as each user interacts with the application in their own unique way.

@easleyfixed, a-dann, Doug Stevenson These are good suggestions but the main problem here is that I actually need these objects created fast as any one of them may be accessed by the new user in less than 30 seconds of sign up.

Also since posting this, I found a somewhat indirect solution to my problem: Don't create and upload a specific blob until it's actually needed by a user. There was no real reason that all 30,000 needed to exist immediately when they could just be initiated on the fly.
Thanks all for your comments!
(Also, I'm new to the etiquette here. Do I leave this question up, answer it, close it, modify it? What's the next step?)

@Joshua: "The reason is that, even though the objects all start off the same for each user, they will ultimately be modified over time as each user interacts with the application in their own unique way." Consider using copy-on-write (or even copy-on-read) in that case, which is going to be far more efficient than a blanket copy-all-on-create.

Maybe pack them in an archive client side so it is smaller and you only handle traffic once, instead of multiple times, then execute an unpack shell script on the Firebase server?
